# Loading issues with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to load 3 swf files into a parent swf one at a time. However, two of them load the third gives a problem. The other two use my custom preloader but the third one fails to recognize it and shows the default flash loader (with 5 dots). But the loading bar loads up properly. And if I trace this.parent inside my third SWF, it shows up null.

Not sure if I am missing something obvious here but the code for all of them are the same.

```
package  
{

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.system.Security;

public class PreloaderMain extends MovieClip
{
    private var l:Loader = new Loader();

    public function PreloaderMain() 
    {
        LoadGame3(); //THIS DOES NOT LOAD UP
    }   


    private function LoaderIOErrorHandler(i:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        trace("IOErrorHandler: " + i.toString());
    }

    private function loop(e:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        var perc:Number = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal;
        mLoadingScreen.percent.text = (Math.ceil(perc * 100) + "%").toString();
    }

    private function done(e:Event):void
    {
        addChild(l);
    }


    private function LoadGame1():void // THIS LOADS FINE
    {
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, LoaderIOErrorHandler);
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop);
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);
        l.load(new URLRequest("SWF1.swf"));
        l.x = 20;
        l.y = 100;
    }

    private function LoadGame2():void //THIS LOADS FINE
    {
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, LoaderIOErrorHandler);
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop);
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);
        l.load(new URLRequest("SWF2.swf"));
        l.x = 20;
        l.y = 100;
    }

    private function LoadGame3():void //THIS GIVES A PROBLEM!!
    {
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, LoaderIOErrorHandler);
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop);
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);
        l.load(new URLRequest("SWF3.swf"));
        l.x = 20;
        l.y = 100;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's pretty clear your problem comes from the SWF. Any chance we can get the code of that?

Comment: It could also be possible that your parent swf is getting too large. Try just importing the third one first, or use a preloader!

Comment: Check the ActionScript version, all must be same. Also, check for ENTER_FARME event on your swf file. IF swf files try to load somthing from local drive, it`s good to check all the paths and sources.

Comment: I dont know if you worked this out but it seems everything is ok, i would suggest swapping the SWF1 with SWF3 position to see if its the actual child swf problem not the loader